# Seemingly unrelated error after restructuring my Python program to make function reusable

Tags: python, import, structure

so I had the following file structure:

```
crawler.py
sources/source1.py
sources/source2.py
```

crawler.py would import each source and the defined function loadArticles in there. However the function loadActicles is very similar for each source. So now I changed everything to

```
crawler.py
sources/source1.py
sources/source2.py
functions.py
```

I copied the function loadArticles to functions.py imported it in each source via "from functions import loadArticles" and am running it from the source via:

```
loadArticles(source, sourcetype, language, url, dateFormat, textFormat)
```

The imports contain some configuration data and the two differences in the function, the format of the date (dateFormat) and the expression used to scrape the text (textFormat), therefore the arguments.

From crawler.py I am now running:

```
source1.loadArticles()
source2.loadArticles()
```

which exits with an error message that doesn't make sense:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sources import source1
  File "C:\***\app\sources\source1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from functions import functions
  File "C:\***\app\functions.py", line 27
    found = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I start pdb (used it for the first time) following comes up:

```
PS C:\***\app> python -m pdb crawler.py
> c:\***\app\crawler.py(1)<module>()
-> from sources import source1
(Pdb) l
  1  -> from sources import source1
  2     import sqlite3
  3
  4     source1.loadArticles()
[EOF]
(Pdb) n
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I fail to understand where to start looking for the problem. Might have something to do that I am importing a file that doesn't include a function definition? Maybe also that I am calling "source1.loadArticles()" but should rather just run the file?

Comment: What does the code look like around line 27? Maybe you forgot a parenthesis or a colon. Also, if pdb works anything like gdb, you might wanna use the command `step` (or just `s`), since it doesn't skip over functions like it did.

Comment: The code worked before I put it to another file though:

    `for entry in (news["entries"]):

        #Assign variables that can be pulled from feed
        link = entry["link"]
        title = entry["title"]
        pubdate = datetime.strptime(entry["published"], dateFormat.strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M")
        found = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M")`

Comment: I think you're missing a parenthesis after the `pubdate` line. This whole line, if I'm not mistaken is: `pubdate = datetime.strptime(entry["published"], dateFormat.strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M")` which is missing a `)` at the end.